# Understanding: `+`(1, `*`(2, 3)) and how to better code it

Tags: r

What is this code: `` `+`(1, `*`(2, 3)) `` supposed to be doing in R? Can it be coded in a more typical way? How?

Answer (score 24):

If you use operators with quotes (e.g. `` `+` `` or `` `*` ``), you are actually using the standard operators with the typical `function` syntax.

Let's say you want to calculate `1 + 2` using that way. You could do it this way:

```
`+`(1, 2) ## Please call the sum operator using 1 and 2 as arguments.
```

So, since the expression you have posted is `` `+`(1, `*`(2, 3)) ``, it's basically the sum operator, for which the arguments are `1` and the result of the product operator, for which the arguments are `2` and `3`.

Eventually, a typical way to do this is `1 + (2 * 3)`.

Comment: How interesting. In Haskell you use ` around a function to make it into an infix operator!

Answer (score 16):

Obviously this is specific to R, but a lot of other programming languages use it too. The correct term is really **Polish Notation** and it came about as a way of unambiguously determining order without the need for parenthesis, which comes in handy for parsers/interpreters.

There's some good information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) if you'd like to read more.

Comment: It's not really Polish notation when there are still brackets delimiting the argument lists for each function.

Comment: @HenningMakholm OK, modified Polish notation. The brackets are specific R and it's function syntax really. It's the same basic idea though and pretty relevant to the question I think.

Answer (score 10):

This is "straightforward" function calling in R. Recall that *everything* is a function, even operators. Fuller details [are in the R Language manual, section 3 on "Evaluation of Expressions"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Evaluation-of-expressions).

In short, what you have here is `1 + 2 * 3` as from the inside out:

- We first have `2 * 3` as the multiplication function is called
- Its result is the second argument in the addition to 1.

Comment: Should that be "We first have `2 * 3`?

Comment: Yup, will fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This shows how to start following the parse tree of that "functional" expression by using the "[" and "[[" operators to pull out branches of the tree. Expression in R are stored in lists:

```
> quote(`+`(1, `*`(2, 3)))[1]
`+`()
> quote(`+`(1, `*`(2, 3)))[2]
1()
> quote(`+`(1, `*`(2, 3)))[[2]]
[1] 1
> quote(`+`(1, `*`(2, 3)))[3]
(2 * 3)()
> quote(`+`(1, `*`(2, 3)))[[3]]
2 * 3
```

Note that it is the same parse tree as the more conventional infix notation:

```
> quote(1+(2*3))[1]
`+`()
> quote(1+(2*3))[2]
1()
> quote(1+(2*3))[3]
(2 * 3)()
> quote(1+(2*3))[4]
NULL()
> quote(1+(2*3))[3][1]
(2 * 3)()
> quote(1+(2*3))[3][[1]]
(2 * 3)
> quote(1+(2*3))[3][[1]][[1]]
`(`
> quote(1+(2*3))[3][[1]][[2]]
2 * 3
> quote(1+(2*3))[3][[1]][[2]][[1]]
`*`
> quote(1+(2*3))[3][[1]][[2]][1]
`*`()
> `+`(1, `*`(2, 3))
[1] 7
```

And you can recover the infix notation:

```
> quote(`+`(1, `*`(2, 3)))[c(1,2,3)]
1 + 2 * 3

> z <- quote(`+`(1, `*`(2, 3)))
> z[1:length(z)]
1 + 2 * 3
```